# Where does the Windows Device Manager fetch his data?

Tags: windows-7, device-manager

The question is pretty simple. I wonder where does the Device Manager fetch his data to build the devices list.

- Is it reading a table (Or more than one) in the WMI database ?
- Is it scanning all the ports periodically to build a list ?
- Is it a combination of the two methods above ?
- Or even something completely different ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [WMI Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394587(v=vs.85).aspx)

> WMI tasks for computer hardware obtain information about the presence,
>   state, or properties of hardware components.

Windows device manager totally depends on WMI tasks.

Comment: Thanks. This comfort me in the idea that it was looking in the WMI tables to get its information.